# How to split entries of RDD[(String,List[(String,String,String,String)])]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I need to apply some processing to an rdd with the following format:

```
RDD[(String,List[(String,String,String,String)])]
```

Here's are sample entries from the RDD:

```
(600,List((5,111,1,1), (15,111,1,5), (38,111,2,null))
(700,List((5,111,1,1), (35,111,1,5), (39,111,2,null))
```

I need to split each entry into several entries based on timestamp values which is found in the first element of each tuple in the List. Each entry should contain timestamps within the interval of 20 minutes.

For example, the first entry should be splitted into 2 entries:

```
List((5,111,1,1), (15,111,1,5))
List((38,111,2,null))
```

The final result should be `RDD[(String,List[(String,String,String,String)])]`:

```
(600,List((5,111,1,1), (15,111,1,5)))
(600,List((38,111,2,null)))
(700,List((5,111,1,1))
(700,List((35,111,1,5), (39,111,2,null))
```

Any hint how to do this and which functions to apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `splitList` function that splits a list from a given record per your desired behavior (not sure I followed it accurately, description is a bit ambiguous), and then use **`flatMap`** to "split" each key-value record into several records:

```
def doStuff() = {
  val input: RDD[(String,List[(String,String,String,String)])] = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    ("600",List(("5","111","1","1"), ("15","111","1","5"), ("38","111","2",null))),
    ("700",List(("5","111","1","1"), ("35","111","1","5"), ("39","111","2",null)))
  ))

  def splitList(l: List[(String,String,String,String)]): Iterable[List[(String,String,String,String)]] = {
    l.groupBy(_._1.toInt / 20).values // or any other logic
  }

  val result = input.flatMap { case (k, l) => splitList(l).map(sublist => (k, sublist)) }

  result.foreach(println)
  // prints: 
  // (600,List((38,111,2,null)))
  // (600,List((5,111,1,1), (15,111,1,5)))
  // (700,List((35,111,1,5), (39,111,2,null)))
  // (700,List((5,111,1,1)))
}
```

Comment: When I apply your code, I get an error `Tas not serializable`, `Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException`

Comment: My code snippet is:  `val rdd = sc.textFile("...") val splitted = rdd.map(line => line.split(",")) val processed = splitted.map(x=>(x(1),List((x(0),x(2),x(3),x(4))))) val separated = processed.flatMap { case (k, l) => splitList(l).map(sublist => (k, sublist)) }`

Comment: Oh, that depends on where the `splitList` is defined - if it's a method of an unserializable _class_, it would fail. Best is to place it in an _`object`_ (which means it doesn't have to be serialized), or a definition inside another method, it should work.

Comment: Ok, now it works with the `object`, but just curious which of these two options is more efficient? also, could you please tell me what do you mean by `definition inside another method` (any small example)?

Comment: difference in efficiency is negligible, if it even exists. definition in another method is simply placing this `def` inside the body of the method calling `flatMap` - updated my answer to show this.